# getting error when i want to send data to the java backend from angular front end

Tags: java, angular, backend

this is the code of the signup.component.ts in which i am facing the error

```
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css'],
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private userService:UserService) {}

  public user = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
  };

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  formSubmit() {
    console.log(this.user);
    if (this.user.username == '' || this.user.username == null) {
      alert('user is requierde ');
      return;
    }

    //add user
    this.userService.addUser(this.user).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        //success
        console.log(data);
        alert('success');
      },
      (error) => {
        //error
        console.log(error);
        alert('something went wrong');
      }
    );
  }
}
```

in given code the "subscribe" is getting depricated and hence i am not able to send the data from form to the backend database

please help me to solve these error
these is the user.service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import baseUrl from './helper';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient)  {}

   //add user
  public addUser(user:any)
  {

    return this.http.post(`${baseUrl}/user/`,user);

  }
}
```

when i am trying to run the code it is showing the following error

Error is given below

```
Error: src/app/pages/signup/signup.component.ts:32:22 - error TS2339: Property 'addUser' does not exist on type 'UserService'.     

32     this.userService.addUser(this.user).subscribe(
                        ~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/pages/signup/signup.component.ts:33:8 - error TS7006: Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.

33       (data) => {
          ~~~~


Error: src/app/pages/signup/signup.component.ts:38:8 - error TS7006: Parameter 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type.

38       (error) => {
          ~~~~~




** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


× Failed to compile.
PS C:\Users\admin\Desktop\java exam project\examfront>
```

Comment: your UserService dont have addUser method